# Some Images are not being loaded after running npm run build in vue

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, npm-run

I finished my Vue app and ran `npm run build` to deploy the app. Everything seems to be fine. However, some of my images will not run. Four of my images render just fine. However, those four images are not in my `img` folder. On the console, I get this error:

```
GET file:///C:/static/img/Two.550dff0.jpeg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The image name is "Two.550dff0.jpeg" and it is in the `img` folder but the app cannot access it. Why is that? Also, for the four images that render, those images are not in the `img` folder. I also cannot find those four images in the `dist` folder. 
This is the index.HTML code:

```
 <script type=text/javascript src=static/js/manifest.1f30a815db1d214533a9.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=static/js/vendor.0757592c5dae8c3165a1.js></script>
  <script type=text/javascript src=static/js/app.53c259c8c3df1ec9179f.js></script>
```

Comment: Not sure why that happens but you should serve your app using an http server.

Comment: If you have python installed. Run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` in your `dist` folder then access it from your browser via `localhost:8000`.

Comment: I did that and I got a blank page

Comment: Show us some code, maybe your `index.html`

Comment: I edited to put the code in the original post

Comment: Try `npm install -g http-server` then run `http-server -o` from your dist folder.